# Copy subset of items from one RadComboBox to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik, webforms

I'm trying to *copy* a subset of RadComboBoxItems from one RadComboBox to another. Currently, I'm trying to do this using the enumerable Where() method. Although the items are being copied to the destination list, the items are also being removed from the source list.

**EDIT:**
Just for clarification, I know there are other ways to accomplish this, but I was wondering about how to do this with Enumerable LINQ methods. It seems like it should be possible, and I've seen examples of copying list items to another list.

**EDIT**: Okay, so this code works as expected:

```
List<RadComboBoxItem> itemList = new List<RadComboBoxItem>( new RadComboBoxItem[] { new RadComboBoxItem("Mon", "0"), new RadComboBoxItem("Tue", "1"), new RadComboBoxItem("Wed", "2") });

//result = 1 (original list queried using where method
int filteredCount = itemList.Where(item => Int32.Parse(item.Value) > 1).Count(); 

//result = 3 (original list preserved)
int itemListCount = itemList.Count;
```

But this code doesn't work. It adds the items to ddlEndDayOfWeek, but it also removes the filtered items from ddlStartDayOfWeek:

```
ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.AddRange(ddlStartDayOfWeek.Items.ToList().Where(item => item.Index > ddlStartDayOfWeek.SelectedIndex));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the source list:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlStartDayOfWeek" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStartDayOfWeek_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Sunday" Value="0" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Monday" Value="1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Tuesday" Value="2" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Wednesday" Value="3" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Thursday" Value="4" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Friday" Value="5" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Saturday" Value="6" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Here is the destination list:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlEndDayOfWeek" runat="server" Skin="Sunset" Font-Size="12px" Font-Names="Verdana" Width="150" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEndDayOfWeek_SelectedIndexChanged"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

ddlEndDayOfWeek will not be displayed unless the user clicks an "Add Range" button, at which point ddlEndDayOfWeek will be displayed and populated with a list days falling after the selected day from ddlStartDayOfWeek. If the user selects a different day from ddlStartDayOfWeek, ddlEndDayOfWeek will be filtered again. For example, if Thursday is selected from ddlStartDayOfWeek, only Friday and Saturday will be displayed in ddlEndDayOfWeek. Basically, the user has to select a range of days, and the end range cannot be less than the start range.

I would like to get this working the way that I've intended. Here is the code I'm using to populate ddlEndDayOfWeek:

```
protected void PrepareRangeSpecifier()
{
    //clear the selection and items from the end range list
    if (ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlEndDayOfWeek.ClearSelection();
        ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Clear();
    }

    //if the user has chosen to enter a range
    if(plcEndRange.Visible)
    {
        //populate the end range with days falling after the start range
        ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.AddRange(ddlStartDayOfWeek.Items.Where(listItem => listItem.Index > ddlStartDayOfWeek.SelectedIndex));

        //if the end range contains items select the first one
        if (ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Count > 0)
            ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.FirstOrDefault().Selected = true; 
    }
}
```

This works great, except for the fact that when I add the items to ddlEndDayOfWeek, they are removed from ddlStartDayOfWeek. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it? Is this how the Where() method is supposed to work? I've tried putting the results of the Where() method into a List, hoping that if I wasn't working directly off the Items collection that ddlStartDayOfWeek wouldn't be affected, but that didn't work either.

If possible, I would like to find a solution that is similar to what I'm doing now. I would really appreciate some help in getting this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to accomplish this with the Enumerable LINQ methods, but finally I just decided to do it in the old tried-and-true way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Prepares the range specifier.
/// </summary>
private void PrepareRangeSpecifier()
{                  
    //clear the items from the end range list
    ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Clear();

    if (pnlEndDayOfWeek.Visible)
    {
        foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in ddlStartDayOfWeek.Items)
        {
            //insert the list items from the start range list
            if (item.Index > ddlStartDayOfWeek.SelectedIndex)
                ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(item.Text, item.Value));
        }

        //set end range panel visibility
        pnlEndDayOfWeek.Visible = ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Count > 0;
    }

    //if the end range has any items
    if (ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.Count > 0)
        ddlEndDayOfWeek.Items.FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;
}
```

I do appreciate the contributions from others, and new answers are still welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried, but it seems that this happens because you are adding RadComboBoxItem objects *that already exist on the page* to another RadComboBox. You should just copy the values and texts of the selected RadComboBoxItem collection into new RadComboBoxItems instead of (probably) sort of moving the objects themselves from one RadComboBox to another.

Comment: I've fiddled around with that idea, but I can't figure out how to do it in LINQ. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried something like dlEndDayOfWeek.Items.AddRange(ddlStartDayOfWeek.Items.Where(listItem => listItem.Index > ddlStartDayOfWeek.SelectedIndex).Select (x => new {x.Value, x.Text }));? I have no Telerik controls here so I couldn't test, but you get the idea - just create new ListItems.

Comment: The problem is that - ddlStartDayOfWeek.Items.Where(listItem => listItem.Index > ddlStartDayOfWeek.SelectedIndex) - removes the filtered items from ddlStartDayOfWeek. I'll give it a shot just to say I did though. I know I can use a foreach to add new list items to ddlEndDayOfWeek, but I would like to know how to do it with LINQ.